# Why can i not create an arraylist of arraylist of integers by using a list of list of integer reference?

Tags: java, collections

```
List<List<Integer>> sets = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

Why does the above give a compiler error and why can i not use the generic list reference here, why do I need to make it specific arraylist reference ?

Comment: `List<List<Integer>> sets = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();` will work, but it doesn't answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that to compile, you would need either:

```
List<? extends List<Integer>> sets = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

or

```
List<List<Integer>> sets = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
```

Answer (score 1):

A `List<List<Integer>>` can contain any kind of `List<Integer>`, such as a `LinkedList<Integer>`. A `List<ArrayList<Integer>>` (or `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>`) can only contain `ArrayList<Integer>`s.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it this way:

```
List<? extends List<Integer>> sets = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

The reason is the same as why `List<Integer>` is not `List<Number>`